# Caching jsonp callback parameter when doing a backbone fetch

Tags: jquery, ajax, caching, backbone.js, fetch

What is the correct way to cache this callback value when doing a backbone fetch?
Have tried overiding the fetch function and setting

```
options.cache = true;
```

but no avail.

Ideally we want to continue using fetch, and not write a custom ajax call.
The below is an example of the callback parameter that is being appended. I need this to be the same return value each time, i.e so it's acting as a cache.

```
&callback=jQuery1111042059096531011164_1421344480838&_=1421344480840
```

If more detail is needed please let me know,

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI.

The solution that appears so far to have worked was to not override the fetch but override the sync and hardcode a string as the jsonPCallback such as below.

```
sync: function(method, model, options){
  options.dataType = this.SYNC_METHOD;
  options.cache = true;
  options.jsonp = 'callback';
  options.jsonpCallback = "onNowCallback";
return Backbone.sync(method, model, options);}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the local storage

```
if (!myData) {
  myCollection.fetch({
     success: function( data ) {
       localStorage.setItem('myData', JSON.stringify(data));
     }
  });
} else {
  myCollection.set(myData);
}
```

Comment: thanks for you answer, that is one way sure, but we still wanted to use the jsonp callback. I will post my solution below